# Republish not working using Sitecore Publish module

Tags: sitecore-client, publishing

We have installed `Sitecore Publish Module(3.1.1)` for `Sitecore 9.0.1` version, except for re-publish everything is working.

On publishing wizard not getting re-publish option and in recent jobs when we click any publish complete item able to see re-publish. When we click on re-publish item versions affected showing zero(0).
We understood republish option not working using `Sitecore Publish Module`.

Please help us how to fix this issue.

Comment: Are you talking about the re-publish everything option? without taking care of anything publish all the items again?

Answer (score 0):

As per the `Sitecore Publishing Service` documentation, the `Sitecore Client Publishing` and the `Sitecore Client Advanced Publishing` roles do not grant access to the full republish functionality.

When you install the `Publishing Service module`, the `Publishing Service Administrator` role is created. This role has full access to the `Publishing Service` features, including the `full republish functionality` on the `Publishing Dashboard`.

To avoid security permission conflicts, ensure that users that must be able to perform a full republish are members of the `Publishing Service Administrator` role and not members of the `Sitecore Client Publishing` or
`Sitecore Client Advanced Publishing` roles.

For more information use the below link and click on `Installation Guide` to download the PDF.

[Sitecore Publishing Service 3.1.1 Installation Guide](https://dev.sitecore.net/Downloads/Sitecore_Publishing_Service/31/Sitecore_Publishing_Service_31_Update1.aspx)

Then jump onto `page 30 (section 4.5 - security)` from the index.

Hope this answer your question.

Comment: I have include Publishing Service Administrator role still am not able to see re-publish option on item publish option. @Sumit

Comment: Did you go through the document I have shared?

Comment: Have gone through that document, what ever steps there i followed but didnt help me

Comment: Did you change in the config file given in the step 4.5.1?